# Visual Studio added spaces on empty line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, resharper, resharper-2019

a couple of days ago I updated my VS to Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.8.3 (+resharper 2020.3 version)
And I catch the next case: VS begins to add spaces for an empty line (on the enter keyboard press).

[edit]: This is a ReSharper option. As mentioned by Piers Myers in the comments.

[image]

But before it adds spaces only after I write something in a new line:
[image]

Maybe somebody resolves this?

Comment: This is a ReSharper feature as I have suspended ReSharper and it goes back to the blank lines when pressing return. Just need to find which 1 of the 1000's of formatting options to change to disable it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a ReSharper bug and they are working on it. I will edit this answer when they will release a fix.

**[Edit]:** The fix will be available in 2020.3.1 version of resharper.

Link to the issue:  [RSRP-482555](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-482555)

Comment: ReSharper 2020.3.1 is now available and this bug has been fixed.